# All linear inequalities on probabilities of pairwise intersection of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ be events in some probability space. Let $P_i=\Pr[A_i]$ and $P_{i,j}=\Pr[A_i\cap A_j]$ for $i\neq j$.

I'm looking for an exhaustive list of all linear inequalities that must be satisfied by the $P_i,P_{i,j}$.

Here are a few categories of inequalities:

1. The Boole–Fréchet inequalities tell us that $$P_i+P_j-1\leq P_{i,j}\leq P_i,P_j$$
2. The Bonferroni inequalities give us some more, as:
   $$1\geq \Pr[\cup_{1\leq i\leq n} A_i]\geq \sum_{1\leq i\leq n} P_i - \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}P_{i,j}$$
   We can also apply this inequality to any subset of the $A_i$ to get more inequalities.
3. We can also take inequality 2., and take the conjunction of all terms with one of the events $A_i$. For example, by applying 2. to $A_1,\cdots,A_n$ and then conjuncting with $A_n$, we get
   $$P_n\geq\sum_{1\leq i\leq n-1}P_{i,n}-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-1}P_{i,j,n}\geq\sum_{1\leq i\leq n-1}P_{i,n}-\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-1}P_{i,j}$$
   where above $P_{i,j,n}=\Pr[A_i\cap A_j\cap A_n]$.

Are there any other linear inequalities, besides these above? If not, how do we show that the list above is exhaustive?

Comment: I feel like there's an algorithmic way to decide this for any $n$: for any $S\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$ let $P_S = Pr( \bigcap_{i\in S} A_i \cap \bigcap_{j\notin S} A_j)$, so that $P_S\ge0$ and $\sum_{S\subset\{1,\dots,n\}} P_S=1$. I feel like all inequalities can be inferred from these after writing $P_i = \sum_{S\subset\{1,\dots,n\},\ i\in S} P_S$ and similarly for $P_{i,j}$.